# Will these data ever become mismatched through processing?

Tags: python, data-structures

I have a function that returns the dates and values of certain stock tickers.

```
def getData(ticker):
     # logic
     return dates, values

dates_list, values_list = getData("TVIX")
```

Although these lists of dates and values are properly paired up now (i.e. each value has the same index as its original observation date), a quick sort on either vector would remove this relationship. Is it better to return something like this as a tuple, so that each observation really can't get "get away" from its value?

I'm thinking of something like:

```
def getData(ticker):
    # logic
    ret_list = []
    date_value = (d, v)    # for a particular observation
    ret_list.append(date_value)
    return ret_list
```

Running this second iteration of `getData` would yield something like (the data do not actually reflect `TVIX` values):

```
>>> x = getData("TVIX")
>>> for pair in x:
        print(pair)

("2013/01/01", 120)
("2013/01/02", 121)
("2013/01/03", 127)
```

Comment: Yes, and then when/if you need to iterate over them, you can use the `zip` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is better to keep the values coupled that are related, so that when these values are sorted, these are sorted together. And you can achieve that just by replacing your return statement with

```
return zip(dates, values)
```

No need to change internal logic of `getData`.